# ruby on rails code syntax including some haml and model view control

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have following  piece of code. Here is the original post
[Conditionally setting CSS style from ruby controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646815/conditionally-setting-css-style-from-ruby-controller)

```
%th{:class => @title_header}= link_to 'Title', my_path(:sort => 'title'), :id => 'title_header'
```

I know that  the link_to work

1.I dont understand what is :class and is :class a keyword?

2.I understand that when we create a model and we will get a model_path,
but in this case why we can pass an argument into my_path?

3.Is that :sort also a keyword in rails?

4.is :id a keyword in rails?

5.so in this case , what we doing with my_path? is it going to return something?

6.how about the :id, what it does in this case??

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:sort and :class are symbols in Ruby, representing identifiers that don't change in code the way a string can.  They are being used as the key in a hash definition of keys/values.

When you pass a hash of name/value pairs to a tag like %th in HAML, it convents them into HTML attributes on the tag.  This allows you to dynamically set the value of the "class" attribute on the TH tag with a list of class names from the instance variable @title_header.

my_path is a named route helper that represents a function to generate the URI for a route named in the Rails routeset.  You can pass a variety of options to change how the URI is generated.  By default, any option that isn't a route generation option gets injected as a query parameter on the URI generated.  So if my_path => /my/path, then my_path(:foo => 'bar') => /my/path?foo=bar.

In this case, this query parameter likely dictates the sort order of the data generated at that URI.

In the same way, the link_to function takes an option hash as it's last argument that determines how the link element is generated.  The last option set on this function is the html_options, where the attributes of the hash map to attributes of the A tag generated.  In this case, the :id symbol and value in the hash will generate an "id" HTML attribute with the given value.

Since you asked, here's a good reference on what a CSS class is: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php

Comment: what is the class attributes for??

Comment: When you write HTML markup, it defines the structure of the page to be displayed.  Stylesheets are applied to the markup to generate changes to the way they look, to style them.  An HTML tag has a list of CSS classes applied to it that dictate what style rules to apply.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.but my_path(:foo => 'bar') should generate the link my?foo=bar. Then the question comes, which method it will enter inside the controller file?   And what else can we put except :id at the last field?

Comment: Only you can answer this.  Run "rake routes" and see where the my_path named route maps to a particular controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

```
%th{:class => @title_header}= link_to 'Title', my_path(:sort => 'title'), :id => 'title_header'
```

will be

```
<th class="value of ruby variable @title_header">
  <a href="value_of_my_path?sort=title" id="title_header">Title</a>
</th>
```

what is the class attributes for?

This is css class definition for th element.